# reliably find pixel 0,0 of a stream in gstreamer plugin

Tags: gstreamer

I am writing a gstreamer plugin that modifies the buffer in place. I use GST_VIDEO_FRAME_WIDTH(frame) and GST_VIDEO_FRAME_HEIGHT(frame) to get the width and height of the buffer. However, this does not reflect what actaully appears on the screen.

example pipe with cropping:

```
xinit /usr/local/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx,width=500,height=500 ! videocrop top=100 left=0 bottom=0 right=100 ! myplugin ! latencydetect debug=1 ! vaapisink sync=false
```

The output will be 400x400, however the plugin will still see a buffer of 500x500.

How can I find the width, height, xoffset and yoffset so that I can correctly locate pixels in the buffer?

I have tried inspecting the caps, which does provide the correct width and height, but does not include the offsets.

Comment: You may try adding caps `... ! video/x-raw,width=400,height=400,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1 ! ...` after videocrop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`videocrop` most likely does not change the buffer, but adds cropping meta data to it.

See https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideometa.html?gi-language=c#GstVideoCropMeta for the meta data structure.

Use https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideometa.html#gst_buffer_get_video_crop_meta to get this meta data from a buffer.